# display 3 table rows and hide remaining rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to shorten the table.I have to  display only first 3 rows and remaining are hidden.and at the bottom of the table thers is a link to display remaining rows.How it is possible

code

```
$.ajax({
    url: currentUrl,
    cache: false
}).done(function (report) {

    var testhistbl =
        '<br><table width="680px" id="report" > <tbody id="mytbody"><tr style="display: table-row;"><th  valign="center">User</th><th  valign="center" >Test Name</th><th   valign="center">VM</th><th valign="center">Browsers</th><th  valign="center">Result</th><th id="headerid"></th></tr>';

    recentreport.forEach(function (test) {

        testhistbl += '<tr class="odd"><td >' + email + '</td><td>' +
            test.names + ' </td><td >' + test.os + '</td><td >' +
            result.browser + '</td><td >' + test.replace('Test ', '') +
            ' </td> <td><div class="arrow" onclick="expandRow();"></div></td></tr><tr style="display: none;" ><td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:black;" colspan="5">' +
            test.passfail +
            ' </td><td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:white;" ></td></tr>';
    });
})
testhistbl +=
    '<tr id="more"><td >Show More</td> </tr></tbody></table>';
$('#testhistyTbl').html(testhistbl);

showMore(report.length);

});



function showMore(len) {

    var $table = $('table').find('tbody'); // tbody containing all the rows
    var numRows = $('.odd').length;
    if (len > '3') {
        $("#more").show();
    } else {
        $("#more").hide();
}
        $('#more').click(function () {

        });
    }
```

i don’t know whatto perform inside the more.click function.

Please look at table [mytable](http://jsfiddle.net/3mT7z/)

here i only want to display first 3 rows and while clicking show more link i have to display the remaining rows also

Comment: Please correct your fiddle with javascript code

Comment: You're also missing a closing brace on your `showMore` method

Comment: ARE you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/3mT7z/1/

Comment: No ,currently 5 rows are displaying ..i only wan to display 3 items and while clikcing show more have to disply remaing also

Comment: Something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/3mT7z/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Yes.this is corrct.but after showing all results show more link dont need to show

Comment: Please check my answer. `$(this).hide();` will hide your button after click.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **JavaScript Code** for you:

```
function DisplayOnlyRows(count){
  var i =0;
  $('#report tr.odd').each(function(){
    if(i >= count){
      $(this).hide();
    }
    i++;
  });
}

DisplayOnlyRows(3);

$("#show_more").click(function(){    
  $("#mytbody tr.odd").not(':visible').show();
  $(this).hide(); // To hide the `show_more` button
});
```

So, `DisplayOnlyRows` takes count of table rows that should be visible, all the rest rows will be hidden. Also, on `show_more` button `click` event we are showing all hidden `table rows`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how a "show more" button could be implemented:

```
 <button>Show more/less</button>
```

with the JQuery toggle function

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var countrows = 0;
    $('#report tr.odd').each(function () {
        countrows++;
        if (countrows > 3) {
            $(this).toggle();
        }
    })
});
```

Explanation: with `$('#report tr.odd').each(function()` you loop through all the rows in the table `#report` of class `odd`. When the counter `countrows` is greater than 3 you change the visibility of the row with `toggle()`.

Snippet:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var countrows = 0;
  $('#report tr.odd').each(function() {
    countrows++;
    if (countrows > 3) {
      $(this).toggle();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#report {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#report h4 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#report img {
  float: right;
}

#report ul {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 40px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#report th {
  background: #0196AC repeat-x scroll center left;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

#report td {
  background: #C7DDEE none repeat-x scroll center left;
  color: #000;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}

#report tr.odd td {
  background: #fff url(http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/expandable-rows/row_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#report div.arrow {
  background: transparent url(http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/expandable-rows/arrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: block;
}

#report div.up {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#report
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="report" width="680px">
  <tbody id="mytbody">
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <th valign="center">User</th>
      <th valign="center">Test Name</th>
      <th valign="center">VM</th>
      <th valign="center">Browsers</th>
      <th valign="center">Result</th>
      <th id="headerid"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>anju@gmail.com</td>
      <td>Purchase</td>
      <td>VM-WIN7-64</td>
      <td>FF,GC,IE</td>
      <td><span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow" onclick="expandRow();"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:black;" colspan="5">Checking Start button: Ok
        <br>Selecting Art: Ok
        <br>Test <span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b><br> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:white;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>anju@gmail.com</td>
      <td>Art Test</td>
      <td>VM-WIN7-64</td>
      <td>FF,GC,IE</td>
      <td><span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow" onclick="expandRow();"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:black;" colspan="5">Checking Start button: Ok
        <br>Selecting Art: Ok
        <br>Test <span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b><br> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:white;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>anju@gmail.com</td>
      <td>email confirmation</td>
      <td>VM-WIN7-64</td>
      <td>GC</td>
      <td><span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow" onclick="expandRow();"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:black;" colspan="5">Checking Start button: Ok
        <br>Selecting Art: Ok
        <br>Test <span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b><br> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:white;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd" style="display: none;">
      <td>anju@gmail.com</td>
      <td>Art Test</td>
      <td>VM-WIN7-64</td>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td><span class="fail"><b><font color="red">Failed</font></b></span>
        <font color="red"></font>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow" onclick="expandRow();"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:black;" colspan="5">Checking Start button: Ok
        <br>Selecting Art: Ok
        <br>Test <span class="fail"><b><font color="red">Failed</font></b></span>
        <font color="red">
          <br>
        </font>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:white;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd" style="display: none;">
      <td>anju@gmail.com</td>
      <td>Art Test</td>
      <td>VM-WIN7-64</td>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td><span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow" onclick="expandRow();"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:black;" colspan="5">Checking Start button: Ok
        <br>Selecting Art: Ok
        <br>Test <span class="pass"><b><font color="green">Passed<b></b></font></b></span><b><font color="green"><b><br> </b>
        </font>
        </b>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #C0C0C0;color:white;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button> Show more/less</button>
```

Updated Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3mT7z/3/)